# firebaseAuthIsReady disables modals and Sidenav modal in React / Redux / Materialize application

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, firebase-authentication, materialize

I'm working on a REACT / REDUX / MATERIALIZE webapp. When I try to suspend rendering of the DOM until Firestore Auth is complete, the modals and Sidenav modal in my React components stop working.

**BEFORE (Modals in components work):**

```
const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    compose(
        applyMiddleware(
            thunk.withExtraArgument({
                getFirebase,
                getFirestore
            })
        ),
        reduxFirestore(fbConfig),
        reactReduxFirebase(fbConfig),

            window.navigator.userAgent.includes('Chrome') ? window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ &&
            window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__() :
            compose
    )
)

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')

})
```

**AFTER (Modals in components stop working):**

- Add `{ attachAuthIsReady: true }` to `reactReduxFirebase`
- Wrap `ReactDOM.render` inside `reactReduxFirebase.attachAuthIsReady`

```
const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    compose(
        applyMiddleware(
            thunk.withExtraArgument({
                getFirebase,
                getFirestore
            })
        ),
        reduxFirestore(fbConfig),
        reactReduxFirebase(fbConfig, { attachAuthIsReady: true }),

            window.navigator.userAgent.includes('Chrome') ? window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ &&
            window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__() :
            compose
    )
)
store.firebaseAuthIsReady.then(() => {
    ReactDOM.render(
        <Provider store={store}>
            <App />
        </Provider>,
        document.getElementById('root')
    )
})
```

**Package Versions:**

- firebase: 7.5.0
- materialize-css: 1.0.0-rc.2
- react: 16.12.0
- react-dom: 16.12.0
- react-redux: 5.1.1
- react-redux-firebase: 3.0.0
- react-router: 5.1.2
- react-router-dom: 5.1.2
- react-scripts: 3.2.0
- redux: 4.0.4
- redux-firestore: 0.11.0
- redux-thunk: 2.3.0

Comment: Aren't you having a lot of dependencies here?

Comment: All of the dependencies are required. None of them can be removed without disabling the application.

Comment: But redux-firestore when there's already a package called react-redux-firebase.

Comment: Firebase is the Google platform and Firestore is the NoSQL database on the platform. Firebase is required to run Firestore.

Comment: It's only a(n unfortunate?) coincidence that Google chose to use the word "fire" in the branding of both products. They do completely different things.